# Using Sequent Calculus to prove $\exists x_1 x_2 [ B ( x_1 , x_2 ) \rightarrow \forall y_1 y_2 B ( y_1 , y_2 ) ]$

Tags: logic, sequent-calculus

I need to prove the validity of the following formula using the sequent calculus LK:
$$
\exists x_1 x_2 [ B ( x_1 , x_2 ) \rightarrow \forall y_1 y_2 B ( y_1 , y_2 ) ]
\text{.}
$$
I already had a look at the post [First-order logic: nested quantifiers for same variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75566/first-order-logic-nested-quantifiers-for-same-variables) and understand why this formula is valid, but I just can't seem to find a proof for it in LK.

My previous attempts looked like this (proceeding in bottom-up manner):
$$
B ( a , b ) \vdash \forall y_1 y_2 B ( y_1 , y_2 )
$$
$$
\text{--------------------------------------------------- } \rightarrow-r
$$
$$
\vdash B ( a , b ) \rightarrow \forall y_1 y_2 B ( y_1 , y_2 )
$$
$$
\text{--------------------------------------------------- } \exists-r
$$
$$
\vdash \exists x_2 [ B ( a , x_2 ) \rightarrow \forall y_1 y_2 B ( y_1 , y_2 ) ]
$$
$$
\text{--------------------------------------------------- } \exists-r
$$
$$
\vdash \exists x_1 x_2 [ B ( x_1 , x_2 ) \rightarrow \forall y_1 y_2 B ( y_1 , y_2 ) ]
$$
Now for the uppermost sequent it doesn't make sense to eliminate the remaining quantifiers (since I would have to use fresh variables) and so I thought, that there might be some way to apply the cut-rule here. However, I couldn't figure out how to do it. Can anyone give me a hint on how to continue?

Thank you! Best,
Patrick

Comment: Hi Mauro! I started with the proof from the bottom and moved upwards, since I usually find it easier to proceed this way. Sorry this wasn't clear, I added it to the problem description. The eigenvariables are exactly the reason why I thought that I have to use the cut-rule to continue from the uppermost sequent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, eventually I figured it out by myself, not the easiest proof:
$$
B ( a , b )
\vdash
B ( a , b )
$$
$$
\text{----------------------- weakening-r}
$$
$$
B ( a , b )
\vdash
\forall y_1 y_2 B ( y_1 , y_2 ) ,
B ( a , b )
$$
$$
\text{------------------------------------- $\to$-r}
$$
$$
\vdash
B ( a , b ) \to \forall y_1 y_2 B ( y_1 , y_2 ) ,
B ( a , b )
$$
$$
\text{----------------------------------------- $\exists$-r 2 times}
$$
$$
\vdash
\exists x_1 x_2 [ B ( x_1 , x_2 ) \to \forall y_1 y_2 B ( y_1 , y_2 ) ] ,
B ( a , b )
$$
$$
\text{----------------------------------------- exchange-r}
$$
$$
\vdash
B ( a , b ) ,
\exists x_1 x_2 [ B ( x_1 , x_2 ) \to \forall y_1 y_2 B ( y_1 , y_2 ) ]
$$
$$
\text{-------------------------------------------------- $\forall$-r 2 times}
$$
$$
\vdash
\forall y_1 y_2 B ( y_1 , y_2 ) ,
\exists x_1 x_2 [ B ( x_1 , x_2 ) \to \forall y_1 y_2 B ( y_1 , y_2 ) ]
$$
$$
\text{--------------------------------------------------------- weakening-l}
$$
$$
B ( a , b )
\vdash
\forall y_1 y_2 B ( y_1 , y_2 ) ,
\exists x_1 x_2 [ B ( x_1 , x_2 ) \to \forall y_1 y_2 B ( y_1 , y_2 ) ]
$$
$$
\text{---------------------------------------------------------------------- $\to$-r}
$$
$$
\vdash
B ( a , b ) \to \forall y_1 y_2 B ( y_1 , y_2 ) ,
\exists x_1 x_2 [ B ( x_1 , x_2 ) \to \forall y_1 y_2 B ( y_1 , y_2 ) ]
$$
$$
\text{------------------------------------------------------------------------- $\exists$-r 2 times}
$$
$$
\vdash
\exists x_1 x_2 [ B ( x_1 , x_2 ) \to \forall y_1 y_2 B ( y_1 , y_2 ) ] ,
\exists x_1 x_2 [ B ( x_1 , x_2 ) \to \forall y_1 y_2 B ( y_1 , y_2 ) ]
$$
$$
\text{----------------------------------------------------------------------- contraction-r}
$$
$$
\vdash
\exists x_1 x_2 [ B ( x_1 , x_2 ) \to \forall y_1 y_2 B ( y_1 , y_2 ) ]
$$